# Mapping points from Euclician 2-space onto a Poincare disc

Tags: mapping, 2d, points

For some reason it seems that everyone writing webpages about Poincare discs is only concerned with how to represent lines and measure distances.

I'd like to morph a collection of 2D points (as defined by x,y coordinates in the Euclidian plane) onto a Poincare disc, but I have no idea what the algorithm is supposed to be like. At this point I don't even know if it's possible to create a mapping between Euclidian 2-space and a Poincare disc...

Any pointers?

Goodwill,
David

Comment: So what's wrong with the answer you got from @rival at http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=10895 (once you specified you wanted to preserve colinearity)?  I'd like to help but it's not clear what extra info you still need, so pls clarify!

Comment: @Alex, it doesn't seem to give me the correct answer. Maintaining theta angle in Euclidean and Poincare spaces cannot be the answer. Let's assume we have an infinitely long line segment, divided into a bunch of points. If I were to map these points onto a Poincare disc while preserving origin/point angles, then the points near the end of the segment would always be on opposing sides of the Poincare disc. This is not correct. Lines in Poincare space should intersect the boundary at right angles, which means that in many cases lines are much shorter than the disc diagonal.

Comment: I want to let you know that I just discovered this site (powered by the same software as stackoveflow) where this kind of questions might get more attention/discussion: http://mathoverflow.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You describe your data as a collection of points.  But from your comments, you want to make lines in the plane still map to lines in the disk.  You seem to want to preserve the "structure" of the space somehow, which is probably why you use the term "morph".  I think that you want a [conformal map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).

There is **no** conformal bijection between the [disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk) and the plane.  There *is* such a mapping between the [half-plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_half-plane) and the disk, and it preserves "[lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model)", but not the kind that you want, unfortunately.

You said "I don't even know if it's possible to create a mapping" ... there are a number of mappings for you to choose from (see the [Unit Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk) page for an example) but there are none with all the features you seem to want.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand everything correctly, the answer you get on the other forum is for the Beltrami–Klein model. Once you have that, you can get to the coordinates in the Poicare' disk with

```
p = b / (1 + sqrt(1 - b * b))
```

Where `p` is the vector of coordinates in the Poincare' disk (i.e. what you need) and `b` is the one in the Beltrami–Klein model (i.e. what you get from the other answer).

Comment: Thanks Davide, I'm currently travelling but I'll test this asap.